Library libuv expecting stdin, stout, stderr to be open, but for the daemons we should close the stdin and stdout as a standard practice
For the daemon processes, it is a standard practice to flcose(stdin); fclose(stdout);, same is there in the application code, and then we are trying to use dnsutility /usr/bin/host to resolve host name, this internally triggers library libuv, which is giving error/aborting with error:

"host: ./src/unix/core.c:602: uv__close: Assertion `fd > STDERR_FILENO' failed."

So, we are:

closing stdin and stdout for daemon process.

triggering libuv for some usecase, which is aborting with above mentioned error, as libuv is expecting stdin and stdout to be open.


The same code was running earlier, before Ubuntu 24. It has v1.48 of libuv1t64 installed on Ubuntu 24.
What can be the probable solution for this:

Can we ignore/comment out fclose on stdin and stdout for daemons? Are there any consequences?
Can we redirect stdin and stdout to /dev/null/ using dup2()? Are there any consequences? What happens if any library tries to open/access stdin or stdout in the same process flow, will that also be redirected to /dev/null/?


please show a [mre]

There is a bug report about that, but unfortunately nobody seems to be working on that: https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/2962

I recently wrote a library for launching/tracking child processes outside of libc, and I went with option 2.  If the user does not want a pipe to the child process, I dup2 the unused std handles to /dev/null.  I'm fairly certain that is totally safe and preferred.

The daemon function also reopens stdout and stderr to /dev/null. Closing these filehandles only leads to trouble, as you have noticed.
